# Why google Cloud spanner doesn't support window functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I was trying to get metrics on the data which is available in Google Cloud spanner then i realized it is not recognizing the any of the window functions. Couldn't find any relevant documentation either. Checking if Spanner team have plans to implement this in future ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about the issue you are seeing. The metric and what exactly are you doing?

Comment: @NithinSujir i want to use row_number() over(partition by "column_name") window function to fetch few metrics on a table which is present in spanner.

Comment: Nothing in docs because window functions are currently not supported in Google Cloud Spanner.